# Rendering Rails view after Angular view kills CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am making a web app front-end in Angular and back-end in Rails.
I am supposed to use all views in Angular but I couldn't do on certain views like `landing_page`, `sign_up`, and `log_in` pages because I need to use devise.

home.html.erb is a landing page where the user is being directed to when they first come to my web app. When they click `contact` on the nav bar, it starts rendering Angular view and shows since `contact` view is made of Angular. The logic for rendering is in `application_controller` like below:

```
def home

    if current_user
        render :file => 'public/index.html', :layout => false and return
    else
      if request.url == "#{request.base_url}/contact"
         render :file => 'public/index.html', :layout => false and return
      else 
          render :file => '/pages/home.html.erb'
      end
    end
end
```

route.rb set up:

```
root 'application#home'
```

If user is not logged in and click `contact` view, it renders `index.html` which is Angular view. And Angular routes to `/contact/` and shows appropriate view.

Contact.html is like following:

```
<header class="page-header">
        <div class="page-inner">
            <a href="/" class="page-header-logo"><img src="/assets/logo-green.svg" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
</header>

<body>
//the view
<body>
```

When the user clicks the logo in the `contact`view, it goes back to `landing_page` and starts killing the css in home.html.erb. Some of CSS is not correctly loaded and end up changing fonts and fonts color. Why is this happening?